# Stl language in sysmac studio 4bytes to float(real)

Tags: stl, byte

Using sysmac studio, i get 4bytes binary data Data[24], Data[25], Data[26], Data[27] like this,

the problem is that the 4bytes data represent my float data what can i do with that 4bytes lol

If u see below images you can understand my problem....

thank you all,enter image description here

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOJYw.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qx58.jpg)

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do and why it isn't working. Also, it seems like your images aren't formatted correctly. If you could use screenshots or actual text instead of photos that would be helpful as well.

Comment: If I understand correctly your question is "how do I get the value represented by a 32-bit binary encoded float?" In that case, it actually depends. There are a number of different floating point formats. On a modern computer, it's probably [IEEE-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_single-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary32)